# Evaluating $\lim_{a,b\to + \infty} \iint_{[0,a]\times[0,b]}e^{-xy} \sin x \,dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I'm trying to calculate the following:

$$\lim_{a,b\to + \infty} \iint_{[0,a]\times[0,b]}e^{-xy} \sin x \,dx\,dy$$

Trying to calculate by definition didn't get me far. Any ideas how to attack this problem?

Comment: i guess you should use polar coordiantes to simplify it

Comment: How do polar coordinates simplify it ? It seems it only makes it worse

Comment: try integration by parts  twice with respect to x

Comment: @daulomb I tried it, but I got nothing good out of it

Comment: are you familiar with Laplace transform? I guess the result will be $\pi/2$.

Comment: @daulomb unfortunately no

Comment: You have
$$
\int_{[0,a]}\left( \int_{[0,b]} e^{-xy} \sin x \, dy \right) dx = \iint_{[0,a]\times[0,b]}e^{-xy} \sin x \,d(x,y) = \int_{[0,b]}\left( \int_{[0,a]} e^{-xy} \sin x \, dx \right) dy
$$
PROVIDED that
$$
\iint_{[0,a]\times[0,b]} \left| e^{-xy} \sin x \right| \,d(x,y) < +\infty.
$$
That the latter thing holds is trivial since $|e^{-xy} \sin x|\le 1$ for all $x,y\ge0.$

In the leftmost integral above, $\sin x$ does not change as $y$ goes from $0$ to $b;$ therefore it is "constant" and can be pulled out of the inner integral, so  you're just integrating $e^{-xy} \, dy.$

Comment: . . . so my first thought was just work with that leftmost integral, but then I thought that although the inner one is easy, what you're left with after than is challenging and might be what you started with. So I'd try integration by parts twice in the rightmost integral, using the standard trick for situations where you get $$ \text{integral} = \text{something} - \text{same integral}. $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I tried both what you first suggested, and also integrating by parts twice. In both cases I got something in the inner integral I couldn't integrate

Comment: @user401516 : It's done in the answer I've posted below.

Comment: @user401516 : I have this criticism of your notation. If you write $$ \int_A \int_B f(x,y) \,dx\,dy, $$ that means $\displaystyle \int_A \left( \int_B f(x,y)\,dx\right)\,dy$ and $x$ runs through the set $B,$ but if you write $$ \iint_{B\times A} f(x,y) \, d(x,y) $$ then that does not mean an iterated integral; i.e. it is not one integral inside another, and $x$ again runs through the set $B$ since the pair $(x,y)$ runs through $B\times A.$ BUT you have $$ \iint_{B\times A} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy, $$ with $\text{“}dx \, dy\text{''}$ at the end rather than $d(x,y),$ and it's hard to be$\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$sure which variable is intended to run through which set. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Let $I=\int_0^b\sin xe^{-xy}dx$. Let $u=\sin x,\,dv=e^{-xy}dx$. Then $$I=\int_0^b\sin xe^{-xy}dx=\frac{\sin xe^{-xy}}{-y}\bigg|_0^b+\frac{1}{y}\int_0^b\cos xe^{-xy}dx.$$
Now apply by parts once again with $u=\cos x,\, dv=e^{-xy}dx$

we get$$I=\int_0^b\sin xe^{-xy}dx=\frac{\sin xe^{-xy}}{-y}\bigg|_0^b-\frac{\cos xe^{-xy}}{y^2}\bigg|_0^b-\frac{1}{y^2}\int_0^b\sin xe^{-xy}dx.$$

Thus we find $$(1+\frac{1}{y^2})I=\frac{\sin xe^{-xy}}{-y}\bigg|_0^b-\frac{\cos xe^{-xy}}{y^2}\bigg|_0^b\Longrightarrow I=\frac{-y\sin xe^{-xy}}{y^2+1}\bigg|_0^b-\frac{\cos xe^{-xy}}{y^2+1}\bigg|_0^b.$$ The values at $b$ will go to zero as $b\to \infty$, so $I=\frac{1}{y^2+1}$. Putting this in the original integral and integrating w.r. to $y$ you get $\arctan y$. I think you can proceed from here. Your result will be $\pi/2$.

P.S. Actually @MichaelHardy's comments complete the theoretical part of the solution as we require while interchangin limits and integrals.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \int e^{-xy} \Big( \sin x \, dx \Big) = \int u \, dv = uv - \int v\,du = -e^{-xy}\cos x - \int (-\cos x) ye^{-xy} \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & -e^{-xy} \cos x + y\int e^{-xy}\Big( \cos x \, dx\Big) = -e^{-xy} \cos x + y \int u\,dw \\[10pt]
= {} & -e^{-xy} \cos x + y \left( uw - \int w\, du \right) = -e^{-xy} \cos x + y\left( e^{-xy}\sin x - \int (\sin x) ye^{-xy} \, dx \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & -e^{-xy} \cos x + ye^{-xy}\sin x - y^2\int (\sin x) e^{-xy} \, dx \\[10pt]
& \text{Therefore} \\
& \int e^{-xy}\sin x\, dx = -e^{-xy} \cos x + ye^{-xy}\sin x - y^2\int (\sin x) e^{-xy} \, dx \\[10pt]
\text{i.e. } & I = -e^{-xy} \cos x + ye^{-xy}\sin x - y^2 I \\[10pt]
\text{So } & (1+y^2) I = -e^{-xy} \cos x + ye^{-xy}\sin x \\[10pt]
& \text{and so } I = \frac {-e^{-xy} \cos x + ye^{-xy}\sin x} {1+y^2}.
\end{align}
Plugging in $x=0$ you get $\frac 1 {1+y^2}$ and plugging in $x=a$ you get something that approaches $0$ as $a\to+\infty.$

Then you have $\displaystyle \int_0^b \frac{dy}{1+y^2},$ and that is routine.

**Second postscript (The *first* postscript appears below.):** Above I changed
$$
\lim_{a,b \, \to\, +\infty} \int_{[0,b]} \left( \int_{[0,a]} f(x,y) \,dx\right) \, dy
$$
to
$$
\lim_{b\,\to\,+\infty} \int_{[0,b]} \left( \lim_{a\,\to\,+\infty} \int_{[0,a]} f(x,y) \, dx \right)\,dy.
$$
The question is: Why is that justified? When is it true that
$$
\lim_{a\,\to\,+\infty} \int_{[0,b]} g_a(x)\, dx \overset{\text{?}} = \int_{[0,b]} \lim_{a\,\to\,+\infty} g_a(x)\,dx \text{ ?}
$$
Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem says it's true if there is a dominating function whose integral is finite, i.e. a function $h$ for which
$$
\text{for all } a>0, \text{ for all } x\in[0,b],\quad |g_a(x)| \le h(x),
$$
and
$$
\int_{[0,b]} h(x)\,dx < +\infty,
$$
where, as you see, $h(x)$ does not depend on $a.$

In this case you have
$$
\left| \frac 1 {1+y^2} - \frac {-e^{-ay} \cos a + ye^{-ay}\sin a} {1+y^2} \right| \le \text{what function of $y$ not depending on $a$?}
$$
Trigonometry tells us that $\left| \cos a + y\sin a \right| \le \sqrt{1+y^2},$ and we have $0 < e^{-ay} \le 1.$

**Postscript:** I have this criticism of your notation. If you write $$ \int_A \int_B f(x,y) \,dx\,dy, $$ that means $\displaystyle \int_A \left( \int_B f(x,y)\,dx\right)\,dy$ and $x$ runs through the set $B,$ but if you write $$ \iint_{B\times A} f(x,y) \, d(x,y) $$ then that does not mean an iterated integral; i.e. it is not one integral inside another, and $x$ again runs through the set $B$ since the pair $(x,y)$ runs through $B\times A.$ BUT you have $$ \iint_{B\times A} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy, $$ with $\text{“}dx \, dy\text{''}$ at the end rather than $d(x,y),$ and it's hard to be sure which variable was intended to run through which set.

Comment: I guess what I missed is taking $a \to \infty$ after the first integral. But I'm still not sure I understand, why am I allowed to do it?

Comment: @user401516 : ok, Maybe I should add something about that. Stand by....